# Estimate probability of matrix eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, matrices

I am interested in estimating the probability of : $d_1(A) - d_2(A) > T$ ; $d_1$ is the maximum eigenvalue of $n\times n$ matrix $A$, $d_2$ is the 2nd eigenvalue of $A$  and $T$ is a given threshold.
I will be glad for reference (I want to know how to estimate such things by myself, so a book/articles/ lecture notes or even a name of related subject will be welcomed).

Thanks

Comment: Does that distance become absolute distance for complex eigenvalues?

Comment: This question is missing content. I presume $A$ is random. What is then the distribution of $A$?

Comment: A is an adjacency matrix of undirected graph, such that for every 2 vertices there is an edge with probability x. As I wrote, I care about how to think about the problem (and less care about the exact result)